# Proving the set of all strings of an alphabet is countably infinite

Tags: automata, finite-automata

Let say that you have the alphabet $\sum$ and you wanna prove that $\sum^*$ is countably infinite. If it's countable then we can list all the strings in a well defined manner, but I think that somehow we can always come up with a string that is different to all the strings in the set. How would you do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*I assume $\Sigma$ itself is countable here; otherwise, of course the statement is false!*

First off, let me convince you that it should be true. Consider the following standard enumeration of $\{0, 1\}^*$:

$$\varepsilon, 0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11, 000, 001, 010, 100, 011, 101, 110, 111, ...$$ It should be clear how this enumeration works. So hopefully this motivates the claim that $\Sigma^*$ is countable.

OK, now on to the proof. Remember that $\Sigma^*$ consists of the set of *finite* strings with elements from $\Sigma$. This lets us write $\Sigma^*$ as the union of *countably* many *countable* sets: letting $\Sigma_n$ be the set of strings from $\Sigma$ of length $n$, we have $$\Sigma^*=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \Sigma_n.$$

So the question is now, "Why is the countable union of countable sets countable?" To answer this, it's enough to show that the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ is countable (since this is $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(\mathbb{N}\times\{n\}$)), and this is handled by [your favorite pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function).

Comment: Why can we assume that a set of strings of length n is countable?

Comment: @TheMathNoob Induction on $n$ is one way to do it: $n=1$ is immediate, and for $n=k+1$, the set of length-$n$ strings is a countable union of countable sets: it's the set $$\bigcup_{\sigma\in\Sigma}\{p^\smallfrown\sigma: p\in\Sigma_k\},$$ and both $\Sigma_k$ and $\Sigma$ are countable (the former by the induction hypothesis).